Why are my function parameters in PyCharm docstrings displayed twice?
This is what my function looks like:
def convert_lesions(input_lesions: list, output: str) -> list:
    """
    Convert a list of IDs/class names to a list of corresponding IDs, names, or colors.
    Args:
        input_lesions: Either class names or IDs.
        output: Expected output format. Possible values are 'ids', 'names', or 'colors'.
    Returns:
        List of class IDs, names or list of colors corresponding to the input list.
    """
    conversion_map = {
        'ids': lambda lst: [key for key, value in LESIONS['classes'].items() if value in lst],
        'names': lambda lst: [LESIONS['classes'][class_id] for class_id in lst if class_id in LESIONS['classes']],
        'colors': lambda lst: [LESIONS['colors'][class_id] for class_id in lst if class_id in LESIONS['colors']]}
    return conversion_map[output](input_lesions)

However, as can be seen in the text below, the parameters that appear when I move the mouse into the function name are displayed twice: both in the entire content of the docstrings and later as the parameters and output of the function, separately.
def convert_lesions(input_lesions: Any,
                    output: Any) -> Any

Convert a list of IDs/class names to a list of corresponding IDs, names, or colors. 

Args: input_lesions: Either class names or IDs. 

output: Expected output format. Possible values are 'ids', 'names', or 'colors'. 

Returns: List of class IDs, names or list of colors corresponding to the input list.

    Params:

input_lesions – Either class names or IDs.

output – Expected output format. Possible values are 'ids', 'names', or 'colors'.

    Returns:

List of class IDs, names or list of colors corresponding to the input list.

Meanwhile, I would like the function preview to show an explanation of the function, with Parameters and Returns properly highlighted below, like this:
def convert_lesions(input_lesions: Any,
                    output: Any) -> Any

Convert a list of IDs/class names to a list of corresponding IDs, names, or colors. 

    Params:

input_lesions – Either class names or IDs.

output – Expected output format. Possible values are 'ids', 'names', or 'colors'.

    Returns:

List of class IDs, names or list of colors corresponding to the input list.

How can I achieve this format?
My PyCharm version is 2023.3.5 (Professional).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html#example should it be in reStructuredText format

@AndrewRyan I tried this too, but the result was exactly the same - parameters were repeated too.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-60788/Docstring-tooltip-shows-params-twice may be an incomplete known bug? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322595/duplicate-information-in-typing-and-docstring
